# JAVA Migration 1.6 to 1.8 and 11

Tags: servlets, java-8, ejb, java-6, java-11

I have a project built on EJB framework, JSP and Servlet. So far it was running fine on Java 1.6 but since now Oracle has announced to stop support, it compelled us to expedite process to move to 1.8 and then 11 JAVA versions. 
My questions are -

1) Since entity beans are deprecated as of Java EE 6. What is the best alternative considering time, efforts and performance?

2) Is it a good plan to move EJB 2.2 to 3.2 or we should use any other framework?

3) What is the best alternative to SOAP, JAXB?

4) Should we move current project to SPRING and REST? If yes/no then why?

Comment: There is no “1.11”, only the not yet released 11.

Comment: @nullpointer we have not tried anything yet. It's still in analysis phase and so I was looking to see a mirage atleast as things were in dark.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

> 1) Since entity beans are deprecated as of Java EE 6. What is the best
>   alternative considering time, efforts and performance?

Move to JPA Entities

> 2) Is it a good plan to move EJB 2.2 to 3.2 or we should use any other
>   framework?

Yes, stick with EJB, just upgrade to 3.x and switch to Local interfaces if using remote.

> 3) What is the best alternative to SOAP, JAXB?

You can use JAX_WS if you want stick to web services, or move to REST (JAX-RS)

> 4) Should we move current project to SPRING and REST? If yes/no then
>   why?

Stay with Java EE, it has all required features. No point to learn additional framework. If you want to modernize a bit you could check microprofile features of Java EE. You can check [OpenLiberty](https://openliberty.io/), which is modern, fast, lightweight Java EE compatible server.